# Selecting all pseudo elements of elements with class/id 'x'

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm looking for a way to select all the pseudo elements of an element that has the class `galleryBlock`, as well as a way to select all the pseudo elements of an element with a specific id.

My code is setup as such: a grid of multiple boxes all interlocking, some spanning multiple columns, some spanning multiple rows.

[image]

Each of these boxes also has the class `galleryBlock`, as well as a second class — what the second class is depends on the boxes ratio, as pseudo elements of these second classes are used to give the box a certain ratio.

For example `.square` has a pseudo element defined by `:after` to give that box a square ratio, etc.

I want to be able to, when hovering on any `.galleryBlock`, transition it's opacity to 0.5. I also would like to be able to individually set each pseudo element's colour — a different colour for each pseudo element.

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
.galleryBlock:hover *:after {
    opacity:0.5
}
.galleryBlock *:after {
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
#one *:after {
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
#two *:after {
    background: linear-gradient(green, yellow);
}
/* etc, etc */
```

But it isn't working. I suspect I am selecting the pseudo elements wrong. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your HTML structure as well?

Comment: Try `.galleryBlock:after` and `.galleryBlock:hover:after` instead.

Comment: @HashemQolami Oh geez, yep, that works flawlessly. If you want to list it as an answer I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all boxes have the class `.galleryBlock` — either they have specific IDs or not — the `::after` pseudo-elements can be matched as follows:

```css
.galleryBlock:after {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
```

And on `:hover` state:

```css
.galleryBlock:hover:after {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

In this case, there shouldn't be any white-spaces between [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) because white-space is used as [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

In other words, by using `.galleryBlock:hover :after`, the browser tries to match every `::after` pseudo-element of descendants of the elements having `.galleryBlock` class, on hover state. While we are looking for the `::after` pseudo-element of the `.galleryBlock`s themselves.

---

Also note that only one pseudo-element can be added at the end of a CSS selector:

> **[4. Selector syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)**
>
> A selector is a chain of one or more sequences of simple selectors separated by combinators. One
>   pseudo-element may be appended to the last sequence of simple
>   selectors in a selector.
>
> A simple selector is either a type
>   selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID
>   selector, or pseudo-class.

Therefore, the selector should be like: `.galleryBlock:hover:after`, not `.galleryBlock:after:hover`.